# How to wrap a regular text file into XML?

Tags: xml, text, cdata

I have  regular file and I need to wrap it into XML. The flat file may contain any legal ASCII character, including ',",<,>, newline etc. I also have a requirement to keep the original file content intact, i.e. no encoding or escaping.
Is this even possible? I'm thinking CDATA...
Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You can use CDATA, as long as there is no occurrence of `]]>` in the text file.

Alternatively, you can BASE64 encode it.